# VBA, select row based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

My data is dynamic and the only values I must store are greater than zero and are located in column H. Therefore, I must delete the rows that contain 0 in column H before saving the record.

My current selection is just hardcoded below the data set.

**EDIT**: How can I change my selection process from hardcode to formula based on Column H values for the entire row before i clear.contents
*Specifically the portion

```
`Range("A4:J8").Select

    Selection.ClearContents`
```

Here's my code for reference. 
Thank you!

```
Sub openCSV() 
    Range("A4:J8").Select

    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    SendKeys String:="%slc{enter}", Wait:=True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not at all clear. How does your code relate to your question? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: First of all you must ask a question if you want to get an answer, you didn't ask one yet. Your post has too less information about a) what exactly you want to achieve, b) where your difficulties are, c) if there are any errors and where. • Please read [ask] and [mcve] to improve your question. A screenshot or example data could help to explain your goal.

Comment: lol, wondered what the `SendKeys` was doing so I stepped through the code - it entered _lc_ in the VBE and then crashed with a "compile error - sub or function not found".  I should've thought that one through a bit more. :)

Comment: Im sorry, I have edited with the question. I am trying to select a row before i clear.contents. I am trying to replace "Range("A4:J8").Select"

This is a portion of my main code. The send keys hits enter to save the workbook before closing

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure I 100% understand the questions.  If all you are asking for is how to clear the contents of a row based off of a columns value then this code should work for you:

```
Sub openCSV()
    Dim lRow As Long

    lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).END(xlUp).Row 'finds last row

    'Loop from the last row to the first (assuming row 1 is header data so stopping at row 2)
    For i = lRow To 2 Step -1
        'Perform whatever test you want on column H
        If ActiveSheet.Range("H" & i).Value = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Rows(i).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i

    Range("A4:J8").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    SendKeys String:="%slc{enter}", Wait:=True
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))
    ActiveWindow.Close
End Sub
```

I am using a reverse loop because I am not sure of what you are asking.  If you end up wanting to delete the row, then this code still works as it's going from end to beginning.  If you only clear contents then you can go either direction and it will still work.

Comment: This code does not close the application window, and the last 6 lines of code is not good coding. Using `SendKeys` is not a good way to save a workbook. The best way to close and save a workbook and quit the application is to replace the last 6 lines of code with; `Application.Quit` and `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`

Comment: Those where his code which didn't pertain to the question at all.  Yes you could clean that up as well, but that doesn't take away from the answer

Comment: I totally agree with @GMalc the `SendKeys` is a **very** bad practice for this and should be corrected to make this a good answer. Even if this was not the OPs actual question, other people learn by using answers from Stack Overflow and therefore it is a good practice to correct such obviously bad things. Last 5 lines should be replaced with `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True`